# How can i parse a user object to return a screen name and move on to my next step?

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitter, rubygems

I'm on code-cademy and i'm in Step 2 of learning twittr api in rubygem (i think its called)... I did Step 1 easy. 
This is what the second lesson reads...

The response from the verify_credentials.json endpoint contains a JSON-encoded representation of the authenticating user for successful requests. Now you will parse the API response and print out the current user's screen name.

Add code to decode the HTTP response into a Ruby object. To do this:

Instructions (these are their instructions)

Add a dependency for the json package (Which json package?)
Access the HTTP response body (How do i do this?)
Decode the JSON-encoded response
Make sure to assign the parsed response to the user variable!
?

(I even read the hint they gave me...here it is below)

Hint

Dependencies can be added by adding   require ''   to the top of the source file. (What package am i supposed to be adding?)

The response variable will have a property named body which contains the text of the HTTP response.

You can call JSON.parse to decode a JSON-encoded string. This method returns a decoded object.

I tried what I thought was the correct code, but that ended up being incorrect. What do I need to enter in order for my lesson to be successful?
Here is the code they gave me below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'

# Parse a response from the API and return a user object.
def parse_user_response(response)
  user = nil

  # Check for a successful request
  if response.code == '200'
    # Parse the response body, which is in JSON format.
    # ADD CODE TO PARSE THE RESPONSE BODY HERE
    user = 

    # Pretty-print the user object to see what data is available.
    puts "Hello, #{user["screen_name"]}!"
  else
    # There was an error issuing the request.
    puts "Expected a response of 200 but got #{response.code} instead"
  end

  user
end

# All requests will be sent to this server.
baseurl = "https://api.twitter.com"

# Verify credentials returns the current user in the body of the response.
address = URI("#{baseurl}/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json")

# Set up HTTP.
http             = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
http.use_ssl     = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

# If you entered your credentials in the previous
# exercise, no need to enter them again here. The
# ||= operator will only assign these values if
# they are not already set.
consumer_key ||= OAuth::Consumer.new "ENTER IN EXERCISE 1", ""
access_token ||= OAuth::Token.new "ENTER IN EXERCISE 1", ""

# Issue the request.
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new address.request_uri
request.oauth! http, consumer_key, access_token
http.start
response = http.request(request)
user = parse_user_response(response)
```

Please help anyway possible. Thank you for your time and consideration. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [ require 'json' ] at the beginning of your code.

Your username will be encoded in response.body, but you need to call JSON.parse on it to decode it properly.

So you have to answer after  # ADD CODE TO PARSE THE RESPONSE BODY HERE :
user = JSON.parse(response.body)